# соединение между компьютерами через сокеты на java

Tags: java, сервер, клиент-сервер

нашел множоство примеров(аля http://crypto.pp.ua/2010/06/soketnye-soedineniya-po-protokolu-tcpip-v-java/) однако все и всё везде делают через localhost,с ним проблем не возникает,но мне необходимо установить связь между разными устройствами посредством интернета, `ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT);` эта часть на сервере,я так полагаю,останется такой,как была, а что передавать в `Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",4545);` вместо localhost на клиентской части?

Comment: там нет ни одной ссылки на примеры кода или непосредственно сам код,а очень хотелось бы их увидеть...

Comment: Потому что это очень высокоуровневая задача. Сложите представление о том, что вам нужно, когда будут более конкретные проблемы, спрашивайте :)

Comment: Если требуется постоянный обмен данными между клиентами, можете сразу подумать про WebSocket server. Можете так же подумать на счет его реализации на NodeJS, если  для вас реализация на Java - не принципиальна, тем более если все это лишь учебная задача.

Comment: >>>"как реализовать такой сервер и как реализовать какой-то доступ с клиента на него". Все очень просто, нужно всего лишь недельку поработать грузчиком и после этого заплатить заработанные деньги фрилансеру, который за день напишет нужный тебе софт.... Ну а если серьезно, то необходимо разобраться из "**сетевым программированием**", "**многопоточностью**", "**графическим интерфейсом**".  Для каждой из этих тем в конце поискового запроса дописывай слово - "java".

Comment: с многопоточностью я прекрасно знаком,а графический интерфейс,как собственно и синг плэй уже написаны

Comment: Тогда, осталось разобраться из сокетами...

Comment: *"останется такой,как была, а что передавать в Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",4545); вместо localhost на клиентской части?"* - разумеется, туда надо передавать адрес сервера. О чем тут вообще можно думать?!

Comment: сервер я запускаю на своем ноутбуке и если с клиента вместо localhost передать ip(например с сайта http://myip.ru/),то клиент не конектится